# How do I choose files from the local filesystem in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to choose some files to upload in Windows Phone 7 (in the emulator), and any attempt to ShowDialog of the OpenFileDialog leads to a Security Exception.  The open file dialog is being called from an event on a button click but I get a

```
SecurityException

[FileDialog_ActiveScripting]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=3.0.40806.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=FileDialog_ActiveScripting
```

Looking up the SecurityException in the Silverlight version of OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog states that the error is:

```
Active Scripting in Internet Explorer is disabled.

-or-

The call to the ShowDialog method was not made from user-initiated code.
```

Anyone had any luck with the OpenFileDialog and ShowDialog in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to use classes from the Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace.  The Windows Phone 7 API's do not give you a generic file picker but rather specific tasks such as CameraCaptureTask or PhotoChooserTask.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 5):

The `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` are explictly not supported in Windows Phone.  See 
[Base Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402549%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).  Also worth reading is [Differences Between Silverlight on Windows and Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This demo app for upload/download of files from isolated storage to your pc demonstrates navigation of the isolated storage file system.

[Reference](http://rongchaua.net/blog/windows-phone-phone-pc-connector-through-wcf-service/).