# File Open Dialog in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, fileopendialog

I am developing windows phone application and I need text file import facility in the application. Now what I need is to open file explorer as in windows desktop application or like html file control.

I have googled with each and every possible ways but do not find a solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your work first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489890/how-do-i-choose-files-from-the-local-filesystem-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 1):

Your application is sandboxed, and only has access to data within your folders - so you can't browse to a file. You can only read files you deploy with your application, or write to isolated storage.

Alternately you could download a file from Skydrive

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. Now can you please give me code to view folder list (total files/folders in Windows Phone), so that i can pick file/folder path by selecting file/folder and then can read that file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to browse for files in a WP application. There is no file browser supported!

You can only access the file stored in the IsolatedStorage of your application. For that you will need to create a file browser yourself which will only give access to files in the Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read files stored on the SD card, but only if you registered your app to manage a specific extension. Txt files are not supported, since they are registered by the OS and can't be replaced.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. Now can you please give me code to view folder list (total files/folders in Windows Phone), so that i can pick file/folder path by selecting file/folder and then can read that file.